# enqueue style and js file regardless of its name

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way in WordPress to enqueue both css and js in the functions file regardless of its filename. I'm compiling sass and es6/js to pure css and es5/js and adding a random string to the filename to prevent cache problems. Like is there a solution where you can enqueue a file like a wildcard. Its always only one css and one js file, but the name changes after compiling.

```
wp_enqueue_style('my-theme', 'path/file.39483908.css', false );
```

where i want to `39483908` to be a wildcard.

Any solution?

Answer (score -1):

First, let me say I believe you're going about this the wrong way, I'll explain in a moment. There's likely a way to do what you want, but it's less than ideal, and prone to issues (left over files getting in the way, version tracking becoming harder, etc.)

You could theoretically use PHP's [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function to get the css/js files in a directory, and load them. Something like:

```
foreach( glob( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/patch/file.*.css' ) as $file ){
    // enqueue them "all" (hopefully one…) here.
}
```

That said, I want to elaborate on what I think is an arguably better way to do this, and that's to make use of the `$version` argument for [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) and [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). This is actually the "appropriate" way to do it. The "Easy" way would be to just increment the `$ver` each time you change it:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', 'link/to/style.css', array(), '1.0.1' );
```

However, I won't leave you having to manually change that `$ver` number like some sort of caveman. Every time you click that little floppy disk icon and save (or recompile) your file, it gets a handy bit of data that PHP can pick up on, called the "file modified time".

Using PHP's `filemtime()` function in the `$ver` argument, you can append the file's modified time (in timestamp format) to the src (via query string), so any time it's changed at all, it will have a new timestamp, circumventing any caching! I use a version of the following code a lot (as in, on most sites/software I build with WordPress):

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'css/my-style.css', array(), filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . 'css/my-style.css' ) );
```

Do take note, that you'll need the **URI** for the `$src` argument, and the **PATH** for the `$ver` argument, hence why I've used [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) and [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory/) in my example, respectively. Depending on your theme/plugin/MU-Plugin structure, those may need to change, but just be sure to put the URI on the left, and the PATH on the right.

The end result in your HTML will end up looking like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='my-style-handle' href='https://example.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/css/my-style.css?ver=1580412541' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

And when you save/recompile/reupload your CSS, the `?ver=` parameter will change:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='my-style-handle' href='https://example.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/css/my-style.css?ver=1580546830' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

So your browsers treat it as a new file, preventing any caching issues - and now you get the bonus of being able to keep proper version tracking records of your `my-style.css` file instead of `my-style.1235465.css`, `my-style.0489438.css`, `my-style.66223561.css`, etc. etc.